# choosing generated divs by id

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery code which generates divs within a for loop. the divs are getting ids just like "id"+index(index++ inside the loop), and are added inside another div.
Everything works as expected, but now i want to create a function whenever I mouseover or click one of the generated divs. The divs are displayed at the same time, and the amount of divs isn't constant. How can I directly choose a div, when all I know about the div's id is "id"+index?

here's the code which generates the divs:

```
NUM2 = NUM;
for(i = 0;NUM2>0;i++,NUM2--)
    {
    $("#imageBox").clone().attr('id',"imageBox"+NUM2).prependTo(DIV);
    $('#imageBox'+NUM2).css({
        backgroundImage:"url('pic')"
        backgroundRepeat:'no-repeat',
        backgroundSize:'contain',
        width:'100px',
        height:'100px',
        margin:'4px',
        float:'left',
    });
```

I thought about creating a loop, and checking the "id"+index with the loop's index, but it's not working.
Here's what I tried:

```
for(i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    {
    if($('#imageBox'+NUM).attr('id') = '#imageBox'+i)
        {
            $('#imageBox'+NUM).mouseenter(function()
                    {
                        $(this).css(
                            {
                                opacity:1,
                                border: '1px solid white',
                            });
                    });
            $('#imageBox'+NUM).mouseleave(function()
                    {
                        $(this).css(
                            {
                                opacity:0.6,
                                border: '0px solid white',
                            });
                    });

            $('#imageBox'+NUM).click(function()
                    {
                        alert("test");
                    });
        }
    }
```

I hope you can help me

cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating the divs you could give them a common class or data attribute that you can then key off of later. For instance, you are already setting the CSS on them explicitly but if you had a CSS class called imageClass then all you'd have to do is set those properties one time in your CSS file and all the clones would have the appropriate style.

Secondly, you could key your click, mouse enter, and mouse leave events off of the css class $(".imageBox") and by putting the 'NUM' variable value in a data attribute you could do $(this).data('Num') to figure out which DIV you were working with in the event (if that's a requirement)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set the handlers individually. Give the divs a class and use event handlers with delegation:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).css({
            opacity: 1,
            border: '1px solid blue'
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).css({
            opacity: 1,
            border: '1px solid white'
        });
    },
    click: function () {
        alert('hi');
    }
}, '.imagebox');
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using an `id`

You can't select `imageBox`+`<num>` but you can get close enough by checking that the `id` starts with `imageBox` using the attribute prefix selector `[attr^=val]`.

```
$('[id^=imageBox]')
    .mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).css({
            opacity: 1,
            border: '1px solid white',
        });
    })
    .mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).css({
            opacity: 0.6,
            border: '0px solid white',
        });
    })
    .click(function () {
        alert("test");
    });
```

### Using a `class`

Ideally however, you should add the `imageBox` class to each of the elements which will simplify the selector, improving performance and making your code nicer:

```
$('.imageBox')
```

[Here is a demo of both approaches.](http://jsfiddle.net/gqGNy/)

If you need to retain the number when using a class and can't rely on the index of the element, then you would ideally add it to a `data-' attribute.

```
<div class="imageBox" data-number="2">...</div>
```

### CSS for hover events

If the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events are purely for stylistic reasons, I recommend using CSS and `:hover` instead. Another benefit of this approach is that the initial state of the elements (partially transparent) will be correct whereas you will need to make adjustments to the JS to make that work as intented.

```
.imageBox {
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: 0px solid white;
}
.imageBox:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also assign the click and mouseleave handlers when you create the divs

```
 var imgBox= $("#imageBox").clone().attr('id',"imageBox"+NUM2)
                         .mouseleave(function () 
                         {
                            $(this).css({
                                         opacity: 0.6,
                                         border: '0px solid white',
                                       });
                         })
                         .click(function () {
                                            alert("test");
                                            });

 imgBox.prependTo(DIV);
```